# The code from the tutorial is now not working

Tags: android

I've been following edmt tutorial on youtube but the code that he used on the tutorial is now not working. so i decided to change it.

Here is my code:

```
public class OrderStatus extends AppCompatActivity {

    public RecyclerView recyclerView;
    public RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Request,OrderViewHolder> adapter;

    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference requests;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_order_status);

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();


        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.listOrders);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        loadOrders(Common.currentUser.getContact());
    }

    private void loadOrders(String contact) {
        Query query = database
                .getInstance()
                .getReference("Requests")
                .orderByChild("phone").equalTo(contact);


        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Request> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Request>().setQuery(query,Request.class).build();
        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Request, OrderViewHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull OrderViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Request model) {
          holder.txtOrderId.setText(adapter.getRef(position).getKey());
          holder.txtOrderStatus.setText(convertCoteToStatus(model.getStatus()));
          holder.txtOrderAddress.setText(model.getAddress());
          holder.txtOrderPhone.setText(model.getPhone());

            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public OrderViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                return null;
            }
        };
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private String convertCoteToStatus(String status) {
        if (status.equals("0"))
            return "Placed";
        else if (status.equals("1"))
            return "On My Way";
        else
            return "shipped";
    }
}
```

I honestly don't know why is the Order Request is not showing when i run the application i have been searching for the same people who've encounter the same problem that i have in the comment section but i have found nothing.
Here is the link to the tutorial that i've been watching

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C_s2kmRFktw&index=6&list=PLaoF-xhnnrRW4lXuIhNLhgVuYkIlF852V

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried changing this:

```
@NonNull
            @Override
            public OrderViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                return null;
            }
```

to this:

```
@NonNull
            @Override
            public OrderViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.in_recycler(whatever yours is), parent, false);
        return new OrderViewHolder(layoutView);
            }
```

I think it may be because you do not inflate at all. You are returning null at the moment.

But this should be in your adapter. I think this is not your adapter. Place it in the related place in your adapter. You may need to check how to implement a `RecyclerView` again.

Comment: yah i forgot to add that + the i also forgot to put adapter.startlistening to my code, thank you sir